# How to add app explanation for location service in settings

Tags: ios, application-settings, info.plist

I would like to add app explanation for location service usage in setting like below image. Does anyone have idea how to do this? Thanks!
[image: app explanation for location service]

Comment: If you want to add some information about your app in iPhone's setting. You can use "Bundle Settings." [tutorial](https://github.com/Weijay/SettingsBundle)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an explanation in Info.plist in your Xcode project.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>The applicaiton requires location services to workss</string>
```

see the below image

[image]

see the result below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the code in `info.plist`

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application requires location services to work</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application requires location services to work</string>
```

[image]

and also check the location service permission.

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

           NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");

           if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied" 
                                                        message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rurouni's answer is perfect.

Some Updates in Xcode 8. They give us list of Privacy in plist.

From that we can add :

> Privacy - Location Usage Description

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application will use location service for user location sharing.</string>
```

[image]